# Hide file in directory

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I want to hide files from sub directory

From this
`mydomain.com/file/file.php`

To this
`mydomain.com/file/`

Do you guys know how to do that?

Comment: Please share your htaccess file in your question which you have tried to fix your issue, thank you.

Comment: I haven't made it yet

Comment: What do you mean by "hide"? Do you mean that you want to block direct access? Or do you want to access `/file/file.php` with only `/file/`?

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson yes, i want to make `/file/file.php` to `/file/`

Comment: I would recommend that you read up on the [front controller pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_controller) and use it together with a [router](https://packagist.org/?query=router). That gives you an easy way to set up all URL's exactly like you want them. That's also how the majority of modern frameworks/applications do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your home directory/.htaccess, add this line:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1/$1.php [L]
```

This will do this work:

> mydomain.com/file/ => mydomain.com/file/file.php
>
> mydomain.com/foo/ => mydomain.com/foo/foo.php
>
> mydomain.com/bar/ => mydomain.com/bar/bar.php

The idea is to repeat the directory name as filename  + .php extension in your real file system.